# How to center align multiple DIV elements

Tags: html, css

Hello guys I am learning HTML & designing web templates. I got stuck while setting the team member of attached screenshot to center. I want to set the team member align to center but my below code is not working.

```
<!----team-members---->
<div class="team-members" align="center">
    <div class="container" >
        <div class="col-md-3 team-member">
            <div class="team-member-info">
                <img class="member-pic" src="images/team-member4.jpg" title="name" />
                <h5><a href="#">Jonh Doe eh</a></h5>
                <span>Lead Designer</span>
            </div>
        </div><!--- end-team-member --->
        <div class="col-md-3 team-member">
            <div class="team-member-info">
                <img class="member-pic" src="images/team-member1.jpg" title="name" />
                <h5><a href="#">Amanda Fenrnicas</a></h5>
                <span>Lead Developer</span>
            </div>
        </div><!--- end-team-member --->
    </div>
<!--//team-members---->
```

## Update

Please see my css here http://pastebin.com/MrbUKbzY

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Set the .team-member DIVs to display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; and text-align:center to the parent

Comment: Try this: <div style="text-align:center;">

Comment: @Swetha where to add this div tag ?

Comment: @Williams http://jsfiddle.net/x9epjLa5/

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I tried  .team-member{
  margin-bottom:1em;
  display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;
  text-align:center;
 } but it is not working

Comment: Well, you're missing text-align:center; for their parent like I said

Comment: Also, remove their floats if are left floated.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan please see my css here http://pastebin.com/MrbUKbzY please answer where to edit which you are suggesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're learning, then see this: http://jsbin.com/momefi/2/edit

```html
  <div id="parent">
    <div class="child">
      <img src="//placehold.it/160x200/cf5&text=John">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet adipiscing elit amantis sinus tus</p>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <img src="//placehold.it/160x200/f0f&text=Anna">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet adipiscing elit amantis sinus tus</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```css
#parent{
  border:1px solid #666;
  text-align:center;
}
.child{
  width:160px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change col-md-3 to col-md-6

```
<div class="col-md-6 team-member">
```

Bootstrap has rows which are 12 wide.

Also, surround the two "col" divs with

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 team-member text-right">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 team-member text-left">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it covered entire screen now. pics are looking large now

Comment: Neat part with bootstrap is you could show different image sizes based on screen width. You can hide div cols based on hidden-xs, or hidden-sm classes etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="team-members"  style=" width: 100%;">



<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6 team-member">
        <div class="team-member-info">
            <img class="member-pic" src="images/team-member4.jpg" title="name">
            <h5><a href="#">Jonh Doe eh</a></h5>
            <span>Lead Designer</span>
        </div>
    </div><!--- end-team-member --->
    <div class="col-md-6 team-member">
        <div class="team-member-info">
            <img class="member-pic" src="images/team-member1.jpg" title="name">
            <h5><a href="#">Amanda Fenrnicas</a></h5>
            <span>Lead Developer</span>
        </div>
    </div><!--- end-team-member --->
</div>
```

Comment: I added this `style=" width: 100%;"` but it also not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/of9Lcn67/2/

```
 div.team-member { width: 20%; float:left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the a new feature from HTML5

```
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
justify-content: space-between;
```

Not only would this center your divs but will also make the page responsive, i.e., based on the screen width, the appropriate no of profiles would be shown. You need to add these 3 css rules to the div that contains the image blocks.